# Schedule at Fixed Rate with Jitter

Tags: java, scala, schedule

We already have `ScheduledExecutorService` with `scheduleAtFixedRate` method, which tries to schedule a task periodically with minimum jitter. However, what if I deliberately want to schedule periodically, but with say a random jitter between (+ or -) 5 seconds, every minute. Are there any libraries that would provide with such a facility.

Comment: Can't you just add a random number when scheduling?

Comment: @Imm: My use-case demands more than that.